# How to extract specific numbers from numpy arrays based on the repetition of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I have two numpy arrays and want to extract some specific parts of them. These arrays are:

```
arr_A=np.arange(17, 29)
arr_B=np.arange(17, 27)
```

These arrays are number of some points. Then I have other arrays which show the repetition of points along the lines:

```
rep_A=np.array([4,4,2,1,1])
rep_B=np.array([1,4,5])
```

Then, for arr_A I want to extract points that are in the right hand side (`21,22,25,28`) and for arr_B I want the points on the left hand side (`17,19,20,21,26`). I shown these points by stars in my fig. I want to find a way to relate `rep`s to `arr`s for finding stared points. The distribution of my points may change but I always want to extract the left or right hand side numbers.
I tried the following code but it was not successfull at all:

```
points=[]
for i in b:
if i==0:
    points.append(arr_A[-rep_A[-1]:])
    m = len (first[0])
    data=m*2
    if i==-1:
        points.append(arr_A[-data-rep_A[-3]:-data])
```

I do appreciate any help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and clarifications, here is a way you can solve this.

How it works -

0. `fetch_sublists()` generator breaks the list into `sublists` and front `pads` each with 0s.
1. `get_stars()` calls the above `generator` to construct the matrix by `stacking` the arrays, flips to face the zeros upwards based on `orientation`, and saves it to `m`
2. Uses this orientation to find the first non zero elements from the top direction and saves it to `star`
3. Rotates the matrix in the required direction and overwrites it on `m`
4. Finally returns both matrix as `mat` and side elements as `star`.

```
#Generates the sublists with padding 0
def fetch_sublists(arr, rep):
    itr = iter(arr)
    maxlen = np.max(rep)
    for size in rep:
        sublist = []
        for _ in range(size):
            sublist.append(next(itr))
        yield np.pad(sublist, maxlen-size)[:maxlen]
      
#Constructs the matrix based on orientation and returns the side elements
def get_stars(arr, rep, orientation='right'):
    if orientation=='right':
        m = np.flipud(list(fetch_sublists(arr, rep)))
        star_elements = m[(m!=0).argmax(0), np.arange(m.shape[1])]
        m = np.rot90(m,k=-1)
    else:
        m = np.array(list(fetch_sublists(arr, rep)))
        star_elements = np.flip(m[(m!=0).argmax(0), np.arange(m.shape[1])])
        m = m.T
    return m, star_elements


#Case 1 with right side orientation

mat, star = get_stars(arr_A, rep_A, 'right')

print('Matrix -')
print(mat)
print('')
print('Star elements -')
print(star)
```

```
Matrix -
[[17 21  0  0  0]
 [18 22  0  0  0]
 [19 23 25  0  0]
 [20 24 26 27 28]]

Star elements -
[21 22 25 28]
```

```
#Case 2 with left side orientation

mat, star = get_stars(arr_B, rep_B, 'left')

print('Matrix -')
print(mat)
print('')
print('Star elements -')
print(star)
```

```
Matrix -
[[ 0  0 22]
 [ 0 18 23]
 [ 0 19 24]
 [ 0 20 25]
 [17 21 26]]

Star elements -
[17 20 19 18 22]
```

---

IIUC, you are trying to break a list into uneven chunks as the first part. Note, that you cant use numpy to store the final array since it needs same elements in each object in each dimension, and here each of the sublists contains different number of elements.

You can use generators for this as -

```
def fetch_sublists(arr, rep):
    itr = iter(arr)
    for size in rep:
        sublist = []
        for _ in range(size):
            sublist.append(next(itr))
        yield sublist

print(list(fetch_sublists(arr_A, rep_A)))
print(list(fetch_sublists(arr_B, rep_B)))
```

```
[[17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26], [27], [28]]
[[17], [18, 19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24, 25, 26]]
```

What is unclear is what you want after that in the second part. Will request you elaborate on that so I can update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Dear @Akshay Sehgal, Thanks for your solution,But I am not looing for spliting the list. I am just trying to extract some values from the list. As my fig shows, I want to store the numbers that have a star. In scenario A, I want to find `21`, `22`, `25` and `28`. These numbers can be found with using `rep_A` but I cannot develope an algorithm for it. I think proposed code in my post is misleading but it was the only wrong thing that I could do.

Comment: Hmm, so what is special about 21, 22, 25 and 28? Why these numbers? Why havent you selected 27?

Comment: Dear @ Akshay Sehgal, They are the right hand side numbers in scenarion A of my fig. I think using `rep_A = np.array([4,4,2,1,1])`, maybe an algorithm can be found tto detect these numbers. I mean for example the last two numbers of `rep_A` ar the same, so I pick the last one. Then from 1 to 2, 1 level changes, so for the third column we pick the first value of it. Also for 2 to 4, two step changes so first two values of that column should be extracted. In my fig it is easier to see it.

Comment: I can say first four values create one column, then again four ones create another column. next column is created by two values and final two columns are created just by one values. I can say it is a jagged list and I want the edge of each row in that list. For scenario B the trend is different. Frequency of numbers in the column increases.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your inputs.

Comment: Dear @Akshay Sehgal, Firstly, sorry for my late feedback. Right now, I am trying your solution for some real data but I do not recieve the correct answer. For example, let's regard a simple case: `arr_A=np.arange(17,26)` and `rep_A=np.array([1,2,3,3])`. When I try it for `left`, I do not get what I want. It gives me `[17 18 20]` while it should be `[17 19 22]`.

Comment: let me look into it and get back to you.

Comment: could you draw the array out similar to what you did with the previous 2.

Comment: Dear @  Akshay Sehgal, the main problem is the `left` part. I coul not find the right answer from it in the data I have shown. Your result is giving me `[17 20 19 18 22]` while in the fig stared numbers are `17,19,20,21,26`. I mean it did not work for the numbers I wrote in the post.