# Get far right hand data using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not familiar with Python,but aim to get data using Pandas from below data format.

Is there any method to get far right hand data from each row? Total rows of this data reaches over 60,000 and last level of each row is vary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To access the column in `pandas` you'll have to give it a name as well (`'some_name'` for this example). Then it should be as easy as

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path/to/your/file')
target = df['some_name']
```

See [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for further details.

Comment: I believe the question is asking something more complex - it's asking for a way to identify the most rightward non-null column. So probably some combination of `idxmax` and then sub-selecting might do that.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want the last value in each column that is not None. I am assuming that after reading your data using `pd.read_csv()` your data looks something like this -

```
# CREATING DUMMY DATA

a = [['AA000',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
     ['AA006','AA001',np.nan,np.nan],
     ['AA008','AA002',np.nan,np.nan],
     ['AA002','AA003','AA003',np.nan],
     ['AA002','AA006','AA004',np.nan]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['Level1','Level2','Level3','Level4'])
df
```

[image]

---

> **Note:** I [modified an old answer of mine for this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343479/how-to-extract-specific-numbers-from-numpy-arrays-based-on-the-repetition-of-num/65344727#65344727), so if you are interested in knowing what is happening here, do check it out. In a nutshell, I have oriented/flipped the data in such a way, that the values you want, become the FIRST values in each row, instead of the last. That way when you do `argmax(1)`, it returns the index of the first occurrence of the `notna` values. Incase of `idxmax` it returns the column index directly, instead of the integer value for idx.

#### Pandas method:

You can use `pandas` to solve this as -

```
result = df.lookup(range(df.shape[0]), df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna().idxmax(1))
result
```

```
array(['AA000', 'AA001', 'AA002', 'AA003', 'AA004'], dtype=object)
```

Here is a visual explanation for the column index

```
 df.iloc[:, ::-1].notna().idxmax(1)
 |______________| |_____| |_______|
         |           |        |
horizontal-flipped  bool  column idx of first True value
```

#### Numpy method:

You can use NumPy to solve this as follows -

```
import numpy as np

col_idx = df.shape[1] - np.fliplr(df.notna().values).argmax(1) - 1
row_idx = np.arange(df.shape[0])

result = df.values[row_idx, col_idx]
result
```

```
array(['AA000', 'AA001', 'AA002', 'AA003', 'AA004'], dtype=object)
```

Visual explanation for what is happening:

```
df.shape[1] - np.fliplr(df.notna().values).argmax(1) - 1
|_________|  |___________________________| |___________|
     |                      |                    | 
  # of rows    horizontal-flipped matrix  idx of first notna
```

---

Finally, set it to a column by simply assigning it to a new column name in df -

```
df['last'] = result
print(df)
```

```
  Level1 Level2 Level3  Level4   last
0  AA000    NaN    NaN     NaN  AA000
1  AA006  AA001    NaN     NaN  AA001
2  AA008  AA002    NaN     NaN  AA002
3  AA002  AA003  AA003     NaN  AA003
4  AA002  AA006  AA004     NaN  AA004
```